# O365 add-ins disabled when COM add-in present

Tags: outlook, office-js

When certain large COM add-ins are installed on Outlook 2013 / 2016 for Windows. O365 add-ins get disabled and greyed out in email compose, but are still accessible if you write the email as a draft.

Is there a good explanation or solution for this behaviour? Are O365 add-in's not able to function normally when large COM add-ins are installed?

Comment: When you say 'greyed out in email compose', do you mean when the compose window is opened as a new window? For 'still accessible if you write email as a draft' - I believe you mean when you are within your drafts folder in the main Outlook window?
Some COM add-ins are incompatible with office add-ins when COM add-ins introduce custom forms for emails. For the second case when you say addins are accessible, clicking on the button should throw a pop up complaining about custom forms. Do you see that behavior?

Comment: I was referring to the add-in icon / button when I said 'greyed out'. This occurs when writing a new email. I did mean the drafts folder, if the email is a draft the O365 add-ins function as expected. Nothing happens when I click on the button.

Comment: Can you specify the COM add-ins that are causing this behavior?

Comment: Yesware's COM add-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add-ins behavior is unpredictable when a COM plug-in is installed, because COM plug-ins can remove key item properties, change the ribbon or form entirely, etc. As a result, they are greyed out, as we didn't want the add-ins to load and behave unpredictably.